# Passing ArrayList<Object> data using putExtra

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, arraylist

im newbie on android. I need to send data from ListView with customAdapter to detailActivity that show detail's item from selected item of listView. I have seen a few post about it and i still confuse about it.

Would you help me?

This is my data class :

public class ListData {

```
private String title;
private String desc;

public ListData(String title, String desc) {
    this.title = title;
    this.desc = desc;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}
```

}

This is my arrayList declaration :

```
ArrayList<ListData> data = new ArrayList<ListData>();
data.add(new ListData("Sidik Suhendar", "Telkom University"));
```

I don't have idea, how i can send my arraylist data to another activity. Please help me :) give me some example too :) Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your base object, ListData parcelable:

```
public class ListData implements Parcelable {

    private String title;
    private String desc;

    public ListData(String title, String desc) {
        this.title = title;
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public ListData(Parcel source) {
        title = source.readString();
        desc = source.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(title);
        dest.writeString(desc);

    }

    public static final Creator<ListData> CREATOR = new Creator<ListData>(){
        @Override
        public ListData createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new ListData(source);
        }

        @Override
        public ListData[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ListData[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Once it is parcelable you can simply do in the first activity:

```
ArrayList<ListData> data = new ArrayList<ListData>();
data.add(new ListData("Sidik Suhendar", "Telkom University"));
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("ARRAY_LIST", data);
```

And you can read it in the other activity as:

```
ArrayList<ListData> data = (ArrayList<ListData>) getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArrayList("ARRAY_LIST");
```

**EDIT:**

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){   
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>adapter,View v, int position){
        ListData item = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this,DetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("ARRAY_ITEM", item);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Then in the destination activity:

```
ListData data = (ListData) getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("ARRAY_ITEM");
```

Comment: thanks dude :) ! i have 1 more question. I use listView and do i need to send data position too?

Comment: yes, if you need to show info about only one of those items in the array list. If you want to do that, you can simply send only the ListData item you want to display, once it is Parcelable it can be added to the intent extras.

Comment: sorry :( can you give me an example :)

Comment: Thank's dude! You save my day :)

Answer (score 0):

First step: ListData implements Parcelable:

```
public class ListData implements Parcelable {
private String title;
private String desc;

public ListData(String title, String desc) {
    this.title = title;
    this.desc = desc;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(this.title);
    dest.writeString(this.desc);
}

protected ListData(Parcel in) {
    this.title = in.readString();
    this.desc = in.readString();
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<ListData> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ListData>() {
    @Override
    public ListData createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new ListData(source);
    }

    @Override
    public ListData[] newArray(int size) {
        return new ListData[size];
    }
};
```

}

Second step：send data：

```
    ArrayList<ListData> data = new ArrayList<ListData>();
    data.add(new ListData("Sidik Suhendar", "Telkom University"));
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TargetActivity.class);
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("data",data);
```

Third step：receive data

```
ArrayList<ListData> data = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("data");
```

Comment: thanks dude :) ! i have 1 more question. I use listView and do i need to send data position too?

Comment: you can send or not send,depends on whether you need it